# How to add the 3rd element of sub-list together in a 2 dimensional list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add the third element of every sub list together in my 2 dimensional list. I have tried this.

```
total_order = [['Steve', 45, 6],['Miranda', 56, 3],['Alice', 34, 8]]
total_cost = 0
for i in total_order:
    total_cost += total_order[i][2]
    i += 1
```

I am receiving this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looping over a list of lists does not give you the index of a list, but the actual list itself.

I renamed your `i` to `order`

```
total_order = [['Steve', 45, 6], ['Miranda', 56, 3], ['Alice', 34, 8]]
total_cost = 0
for order in total_order:
    total_cost += order[2]
```

but I'd suggest you look into "Generator Expressions" and use the builtin `sum` function:

```
total_order = [['Steve', 45, 6], ['Miranda', 56, 3], ['Alice', 34, 8]]
total_cost = sum(order[2] for order in total_order)
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that in your case is not number but a list. Put print(i) there and you will see.

```
['Steve', 45, 6]
['Miranda', 56, 3]
['Alice', 34, 8]
```

You should have:

```
total_cost += i[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

total_order is a list of lists, when you iterate over that object the way you did, you're getting a list object - hence the error.
You can iterate it using `enumerate` or a simpler method:

```
total_cost = sum([item[2] for item in total_order])
```

Output would be:

```
17
```

if you're not into list comprehensions then:

```
for i in range(len(total_order)):
    total_cost += total_order[i][2]
```

will output the same.

Comment: thank you very much I did not realise it was this simple. it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the second item of `i`

```
total_order = [['Steve', 45, 6],['Miranda', 56, 3],['Alice', 34, 8]]
total_cost = 0
for i in total_order:
    total_cost += i[2]
print(total_cost)
```

OR to use enumarte to iterate by index

```
for i, _ in enumerate(total_order):
    total_cost += total_order[i][2]
```

Output

```
17
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the index method of Python lists:

```
total_order = [['Steve', 45, 6],
               ['Miranda', 56, 3],
               ['Alice', 34, 8]
               ]
total_cost = 0

for i in total_order:
    total_cost += total_order[total_order.index(i)][2]

print(total_cost)
```

Giving:

```
17
```